# Asp.Net Core 2.0 not serving some static file like m3u8

Tags: asp.net-core, m3u8

I can't access m3u8 file,
but there is no problem to access css,txt,jpg,js,... (in wwwroot).
IIs Mime types and web.confing and WebHostBuillder.UseWebRoot settings are done but the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add m3u8 file type to StaticFileOptions provider:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
// Add new mappings
provider.Mappings[".m3u8"] = "application/x-mpegURL";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Comment: Thanks,I added your code but CORS error has occurred.please see this link : https://pasteboard.co/HYxlAj0.jpg

Comment: Your code does not work for me. Could you upload your sample project on github?